# How to set breakpoint with gdb on arbitrary memory location?

Tags: gdb

I'm trying to debug some code on Linux.
There's an arbitrary memory location I need the program to jump to.
This location is result of calling mmap with appropriate protection flags for executing a piece of code.
When trying to set break point like this: `b 0x00007ffff7fcf000`
I get the following message:

```
Function "0x00007ffff7fcf000" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n])
```

If I answer no, then no breakpoint is triggered, and if I answer yes, then still no breakpoint is triggered. How can I make gdb set a breakpoint on this address?

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. While trying to set the bpx, you have already mapped the respective memory range? What does `info mem` give as output? Is GDB even aware of that memory?

Comment: actually, after I added the asterisk before the address as suggested by the accepted answer, it worked just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use syntax like `*0x12345` with raw addresses, otherwise gdb tries to resolve it as a symbol.